# Equality of Isoperimetric Inequality

Tags: differential-geometry

I am following a proof of the Isoperimetric Inequality where we use, in order, Green's Theorem, the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, and the AM-GM Inequality. It was left as an exercise to prove that the curve is a circle if and only if the equality holds of the Isoperimetric Inequality.

If I am to start with, supposing $A(\gamma) = \frac{1}{4 \pi} l(\gamma)^2$, then multiplying by $\pi$ on both sides would yield
$$
4 \pi^2 A(\gamma) = \pi l(\gamma)^2,
$$
where the right-hand side is the area of a circle. But from here, I can't get any further.

Comment: It’s a bit deeper than that. In fact, even in some texts, the argument is fuzzy. You have to start by analyzing all the chains in the inequality and what happens if equality holds. If you get stuck, look at the end of chapter 1 in my differential geometry text, freely available at the link in my profile.

Comment: Thank you so much Ted! I will most definitely check out your Differential Geometry text. In the text my course is following: Elementary Differential Geometry by Andrew Pressley, it notes that if $l(\gamma) = 2 \pi R$ and $A(\gamma) = \pi R^2$ then it is an equality. Would I be able to do that myself as a proof?

Comment: What is the meaning of $R$? You still need to prove that the curve is a circle of radius $R$. It’s a lot more than assuming known formulas for a circle.

Comment: Right. I actually just read your proof briefly, but I will go through it more rigorously and come back with questions. I appreciate the help tremendously!